# Checklist: When to write portable / POSIX-compliant shell code?

Tags: bash, shell, architecture, posix, portability

Many shell developers spend much effort in developing portable code, avoiding for example Bashisms, and I wonder how much this increased effort really contributes to compliance with software requirements.

I wonder if it is possible to give a simple checklist of conditions requiring portable code. Let us assume

- that using shell instead of `$BETTER_LANGUAGE` actually makes sense,
- that each shell has the same version on all target systems (i.e. shell version differences are not part of portability),
- that readability/changeability is not considered for the moment (portable code may be easier to read / understand than e.g. the newest Bash RegEx feature).

This is what has come to my mind so far:

- Code is actually (or probably in the future) and intentionally executed in different shells (e.g. because the target platforms are limited to different shells, or because the code may have to be executed in a faster shell like `dash` in the future) and providing different implementations is not feasible.
- Code is part of a framework that aims to be portable itself
- Code is part of a source package that must be buildable on a variety of platforms
- The software is distributed as a package for a variety of target systems and the developer does not want to introduce a dependency on a specific shell

Are there any obvious conditions that I haven't thought of, or could they be expressed more generally? Would POSIX compliance require a different checklist than general portability? Is there any literature or other source that you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder how much this increased effort really contributes to compliance with software requirements.

This - "this increased effort" - suggests that choice of the shell as programming language was wrong in the first place. Shell is the language of plumbing: you do NOT implement tools in it - you control other tools with it. If a shell script takes long time to develop, if you run into limitations of the POSIX shell, then the shell is very likely the wrong language.

The only exception to that, and something missing from your checklist, is the environment of a bare, as if freshly installed, commercial UNIX system (and probably some of the *BSD systems). If you develop software for such systems, then you would probably have to use the POSIX shell, simply because there might be literally nothing (as in literally "literally nothing") else installed on the system.

In the end, all software comes with the list of dependencies and prerequisites. If you include the `bash` as dependency, it would bother no *NIX admin: `bash` is often the first 3rd party package installed on such systems anyway. Also, compared to other 3rd party software, the `bash` (as other popular shells, e.g. `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`) is literally free of the installation and dependency problems.

> Would POSIX compliance require a different checklist than general portability?

There is no such thing as "general portability". Portability is always *particular*.

Software portability, broadly defined, is a ability of the software to run on two or more different operating systems. POSIX is an operating system standard, defining a part of the OS interfaces to users and software developers. It is a platform foundation, not a platform of its own.

POSIX compliance requirement I have seen only in some niche markets. Often for sole reason that it is the only operating system ISO standard in existence.

For the software which doesn't have the hard requirement of the "POSIX compliance", generally it is recommended to target specific platforms. Common denominator might still be the POSIX standard, but the OS specific features, customizations and handling simply make the software better for the users of the particular platform.

In the end, users do not care about the POSIX. The POSIX is the tool for the developers. Developers use it to reduce the costs of developing and maintaining the software for multiple platform. Thus the requirement, as it comes from the users, is the support of a particular platform, not "POSIX compliance".